# Transform string array to integer array during JSON decode using Unbox in Swift

Tags: json, swift

**UPDATE: This has now been fixed in Unbox 1.9.**

I'm using the awesome [Unbox](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox) JSON decoder in a small Swift project and so far it has proven very easy to work with.  However, I've run into a small problem trying to decode and transform a string array in JSON to an integer array property.

I have a Conversation class that looks like this:

```
final class Conversation: Unboxable {

    var participants: [Int]?
    var subject: String?
    var timestamp: Int?
    var conversationId: String?

    init(unboxer: Unboxer) {
        self.participants = unboxer.unbox("participants")
        self.subject = unboxer.unbox("subject")
        self.timestamp = unboxer.unbox("timestamp")
        self.conversationId = unboxer.unbox("conversationId")
    }
}
```

The JSON that I'm working with looks like this:

```
{
    "subject" : "subject line goes here",
    "participants" : [
        "201984",
        "237810",
        "149092",
        "202577"
    ],
    "timestamp" : 1468322845885,
    "conversationId" : "9bf356d1-4823-11e6a51e-2d6dfda33d93"
}
```

As you can see, the participants array in the JSON is a string array and I'd like to transform it into an integer array. When I run my code, the participants property in my class is nil after unboxing. If I change its type to [String]?, then it unboxes ok.  One of the nice things about Unbox is that it will automagically transform (where possible) a string value into a numeric type for you.  But either I'm doing something wrong or Unbox doesn't provide this same capability for arrays.  Has anyone done this using Unbox before?

Comment: I haven't used Unbox, but if `unboxer.unbox("participants")` yields (as per default for your `participants` object) an array of `String` instances, you could use a native Swift solution to get your `Int` array: `self.participants = unboxer.unbox("participants").flatMap{ Int($0) }` in your initializer.

Comment: ... rather `self.participants = unboxer.unbox("participants")?.flatMap{ Int($0) }`, as the unbox results are optional.

Comment: @dfri thanks, that's a great suggestion!